# Sublime text group opened files in folders

Tags: sublimetext3

Can you group opened files in the left "OPEN FILES" panel in folders somehow? Or like tree layout like windows explorer.

Comment: You should rewrite your question, at the moment it is not at all clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can add folders to the side bar, which you can expand and collapse like Windows Explorer, but there is currently no way to group open files other than to have them in separate windows. However, they are working on functionality in Sublime Text 4 that could enable you to have multiple projects or groups open in one window. ST4 is still very much in alpha status and is not stable enough for everyday use.

Comment: I want to be able to create folder of my own in side panel and drag some opened files in the folder. Is this possible now?